# MySql Modelling import into MySql scheme

Tags: mysql

I just started learning MySql and I have a pretty basic question. I recently created a Mysql model with its tables and relationships and I wanted to know if i can import that model into a MySql scheme since I want to add data into the tables.

Comment: Hello, what you mean by model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download xampp AND mysql workbench, then here you have a tutorial https://youtu.be/w-0IWyAeZ3M on how to do that from min 15:50

Comment: xamp has phpMyadmin by default you can use it or use workbench as suggested by @Rafael_h